# How Firebase Storage limit images domains？

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-security

I use Firebase Storage to put images as image space, and then link to my blog, for example:

```
![example](https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/xxxxxx....)
```

I checked "https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/security-checklist" it is mentioned

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
   match /b/{bucket}/o {
     match /{allPaths=**} {
       allow read, write: if false;
     }
   }
}
```

But it doesn't seem to mention how to restrict the domain, for example: the image can only be read in example1.com, not in example2.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way inFirebase's security rules for Cloud Storage to limit the domain that can read files. You *may* be able to control that through Cloud Storage's configuration itself, but otherwise you'll want to look at Firebase [App Check](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check) which ensures that only your own code can make API calls.

Note: if you generate a download URL for a file in Cloud Storage, access through that URL (by design) bypasses the security rules and App Check, so will always be allowed. Given your use-case "in blogs" that might apply here, but I wasn't sure.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply, I might consider starting a server to fix this.